# Perl object, toString output from within module

Tags: perl, object, module, tostring, data-dumper

I'm doing a class assignment to learn about Object Oriented programming in Perl. I've got a real basic class that looks like this.

```
sub new{
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {
    'Sides' => 3,
    'SL' => \@sidelengths};
  bless $self, $class;
  return $self;
  }
```

I've got two modules to change the sides and length(can't figure out how to modify the sidelegnths with an accessor though) but I have a requirement for my work that I have a method like this

"a method: toString() which returns all of the file attributes in a printable
string. If this is done correctly, the PERL

```
print $file->toString() . "\n";
```

should print a readable summary of the file."

I already think I want to use Data::Dumper to do this and that works within a script but it sounds like I need to use it within a module and call that to print a string of whats in the object. So far I have this

```
sub toString{
  my $self = @_;
  Dumper( $self );
  }
```

Which just prints out "$VAR1 = 1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want here is to `shift` an argument out of `@_`.

```
sub toString {
  my $self = shift @_;  
  Dumper( $self );
}
```

When you have `$var = @array`, that evaluates the array in a *scalar context*, and that returns the number of elements in the array.  So, your statement `my $self = @_;` set `$self` to the number of arguments passed to `toString`, which in this case was 1.  (The `$self` argument.)

Alternately, you can capture the first element of `@_` this way:

```
sub toString {
  my ($self) = @_;  
  Dumper( $self );
}
```

What *this* does is evaluate `@_` in *list* context since it uses *list assignment*.  It assigns the first element of  `@_` to `$self`.

Comment: Actually the `my ($self) = @_;` is generally preferred, and is faster on recent versions of Perl.

Answer (score 4):

```
my $self = @_;
```

is a [scalar assignment operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129), so it `@_` in scalar context, which is the number of elements it contains. You want to use the list assignment operator.

```
sub toString {
   my ($self) = @_;
   return Dumper( $self );
}
```